# How do I Edit Configuration in Intellij so a Play2 app will run?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I created a Play2 app, but when renaming the project from untitled to [ProjectName] left the project in an unworking state, I tried reimporting the project.  Then I tried: Edit Configurations..., +, Play 2 App, edited the Name to match the project name, accepted defaults, pressed OK.  When I try to run, the error I get is:

```
Error running ProjectName:
Cannot start process, the working directory 'C:\...\IdeaProjects\ProjectName\.idea\modules\ProjectName.iml' is not a directory
```

What kind of an error message is that?  Well, duh, of course the .iml XML file is not a directory.  IntelliJ made it, in fact it created all the files, so I would think it would know what it created.  Anyway, I'm trying to figure out how to get this Play2 app to work.

I had this working as a Play 2.4.3 scala app with Scala 2.11 and Java 8, but the target machine is stuck at Java 7, so I had to downgrade to Java 7, Scala 2.10 and Play 2.3.10.  I haven't been able to get Play working since (from within IntelliJ 15.0.1).

Comment: And why would IntelliJ not know that the directory called ProjectName should be the working directory?

Answer (score 2):

Fyi:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147287
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9406
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9536

I'm just reading though the last ticket to see if there's anything in there that'll allow me to work around the same problem.

Our setup is lots of java modules in a project and a single play module with dependencies managed by maven.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new Play 2.3.10 app, which works (runs).  I looked at the differences.

In the project that no longer runs:

```
 196 11-18 12:19 .idea/play2_compiler_settings.xml
1405 11-18 12:01 .idea/play2_project_settings.xml
```

In a brand new Play 2.3.10 project I made that does run:

```
1558 11-18 12:31 .idea/play2_project_settings.xml
 266 11-18 12:31 .idea/play2_settings.xml
```

The filenames are different, and what's in them is different too.  I have a feeling that when you do Edit Configuration..., +, Play2 App, you do **not** get the same config files written for you in `.idea/` as if you had created the project from scratch.  The *create from scratch* approach seems to know that you could pick different versions of JDK / Scala / Play, whereas the Edit Configurations..., +, Play2 App sequence may not have the same smarts.

So I got things running by creating a new project from scratch and then copying my sources from the damaged project to the new working one.  I'm still wondering how the old project got damaged from my just trying to rename it from `untitled` to something meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

I have more specific information.  I went into the file `.idea/play2_project_settings.xml` in the project that had been renamed from `untitled` to a real name, and found this:

```
<entry key="untitled">
  <value>
    <ProjectSettingsEntry>
      <option name="playDistrPath" value="$USER_HOME$/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play_2.10/jars/play_2.10-2.3.10.jar" />
    </ProjectSettingsEntry>
  </value>
</entry>
```

I changed "untitled" on the first line to the new name, to match the other entries in that XML file that had been changed correctly, and then everything ran OK.  So I guessing whoever writes that XML file forgot to change one entry, or maybe a component needs to be notified so it can change the value of the key before writing its piece.